# Unable to indentify the bug in my Reducer join code

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, mapper, reducers

I have two datasets:
users:

```
Bobby 06 Amsterdam
Sunny 07 Rotterdam
Steven 08 Liverpool
Jamie 23 Liverpool
Macca 91 Liverpool
Messi 10 Barcelona
Pique 04 Barcelona
Suarez 09 Barcelona
Neymar 11 brazil
Klopp 12 Liverpool
```

userlogs:

```
Sunny NewPlayer 12.23.14.421
Klopp Crazy 88.33.44.555
Bobby NewPlayer 99.12.11.222
Steven Captain 99.55.66.777
Jamie Local 88.99.33.232
Suarez Spain 77.55.66.444
```

I want to join these two datasets using reducer join.
I wrote my classes in this way:

MapperClass:

```
Public class MapperClass {
    public static class UserMap extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line     = value.toString();
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            String name     = tokens[0];
            String city     = tokens[2];
            context.write(new Text(name), new Text("UserFile" + "\t" + city));
        }
    }

    public static class UserLogs extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line     = value.toString();
            String[] tokens = line.split(" ");
            String name     = tokens[0];
            String ip       = tokens[2];
            context.write(new Text(name), new Text("UserLogs" + "\t" + ip));
        }
    }
}
```

Reducer Class:

```
public class ReducerClass extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String city = null;
        String ip   = null;
        for(Text t: values) {
            String[] parts = t.toString().split("\t");
            if(parts[0].equals("UserFile")) {
                city = parts[1];
            }
            if(parts[0].equals("UserLogs")) {
                ip = parts[1];
            } else {
                ip = "IP Address not found";
            }
        }
        context.write(key, new Text(city + "\t" + ip));
    }
}
```

Driverclass:

```
public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException, InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(MainClass.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setReducerClass(ReducerClass.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class, UserMap.class);
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, UserLogs.class);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));

        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true)?0:1);
    }
}
```

The output should be like this:

```
Bobby   Amsterdam 99.12.11.222
Sunny   Rotterdam  12.23.14.421
Klopp    Liverpool  88.33.44.555
Steven  Liverpool   99.55.66.777
Jamie    Liverpool    88.99.33.232
Suarez  Barcelona   77.55.66.444
```

Instead Im getting output like this:

```
Bobby   Amsterdam       IP Address not found
Jamie   Liverpool       88.99.33.232
Klopp   Liverpool       IP Address not found
Macca   Liverpool       IP Address not found
Messi   Barcelona       IP Address not found
Neymar  brazil IP Address not found
Pique   Barcelona       IP Address not found
Steven  Liverpool       99.55.66.777
Suarez  Barcelona       IP Address not found
Sunny   Rotterdam       12.23.14.421
```

I couldn't understand what mistake did I made here.
Can anyone help me on fixing this problem.
Any kind of help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your reducer, it is overriding IP address depending on `values` order. Try this one:

```
public class ReducerClass extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>{
    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String city = null;
        String ip   = null;
        for(Text t: values) {
            String[] parts = t.toString().split("\t");
            if(parts[0].equals("UserFile")) {
                city = parts[1];
            } else if(parts[0].equals("UserLogs")) {
                ip = parts[1];
            }
        }
        if (ip != null && city != null) {
            context.write(key, new Text(city + "\t" + ip));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Corrected it & worked like charm. Thanks a lot Mariusz.